# A general formula for a specific improper integral

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

The integral I'm after is here: [image]

The question is a little ambiguous whether it wants a general solution for this, but based on thought, I would guess there are many different answers based on the relationship between x, n and a.  It also asks for the specific case where m=5, a=4, and n=4.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The integral admits the closed form

$$ I = \frac{a^{-\frac{1+n}{n}}}{n}\Gamma\left( \frac{m+1}{n} \right),  $$

which can be evaluated using the change of variables $ax^n=t$. $\Gamma(z)$ is the [gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). Pay attention for what $m$ and $n$ the integral exists.

**Note:** The gamma function is defined as

> $$ \Gamma(z) = \int_{0}^{\infty}t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt,\quad Re(z)>0.  $$

Comment: Is there a specific set of values for m,n and for which it exists or is more of a spectrum?

Comment: Check the existence conditions of the gamma function.

Comment: I'm a little confused how you used the substitution to arrive at that solution, I used ax^n and ended up with something totally different, that didn't resemble the gamma function as nicely

Comment: @MarshallCase: You should be able to get the answer. Just work the problem step by step. If you still have problems let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Doing the same as science proposed (which is indeed the simplest way), I instead arrive to $$I=\frac{a^{-\frac{m+1}{n}} }{n}\Gamma \left(\frac{m+1}{n}\right)$$ provided some conditions I let you finding.